# Karate - Display title of called features / scenarios in cucumber reports

Tags: cucumber, karate

I have a very huge scenario, where I have automated an end to end test with a lot of requests to different API. Every service call of an API is in an extra feature file and called in the main scenario.

The problem is, that the generated cucumber report is getting really unclear and I would love to make them a little bit more readable by displaying the title of the called feature files and also the scenario title preferebly. Is this somehow possible?

So instead of just printing:

```
call classpath:feature/rm/msisdn/rm-msisdn-reservation-add.feature
```

It would be nice to have this:

```
Reserve MSISDN  
call classpath:feature/rm/msisdn/rm-msisdn-reservation-add.feature
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

cheerio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this, I've opened a feature request here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/379 and you are free to continue the discussion there.

To be honest we recommend that you use `call` only for the 'set up' kind of re-usable steps that are not part of your 'main' flow. But we understand why some teams would rely on call.

By the way do the called features have multiple Scenarios ? Just curious and we really didn't design for that happening, so please let me know on the GitHub ticket.

Comment: Since I have several end-to-end testflow (main flows), that all use different compositions of the generic API calls (SOAP and REST), I don't see another solution without a lot of redundant code. Or do you have any recommendations for scenarios with a lot of api calls and shared payloads?

Comment: btw this is fixed in dev. will update the ticket when I release 0.8.0.RC3

Comment: you are right, I can't think of a better way. and if you have succeeded in making many re-usable features, that is pretty impressive. maybe I'll recommend this as a pattern after all. would love to see some examples if you can post / blog somewhere

Comment: @backfloep can you try 0.8.0.RC3 and let me know if this works for you ?

Comment: works like charm! Thank you and sorry for the delayed answer.